# Where can I learn by example how to create custom flashcards using random numbers and persistence

Tags: anki

Anki version: 2.1.49 on Windows / Linux / Android

I'm following a guide on how to create persistent, random numbers using Anki.  The guide is [here](https://www.yingtongli.me/blog/2015/03/15/random-question-generator-on-anki-using.html) I can't get it work because the author doesn't tell you where to put what on over half of the guide.  His examples are exactly what I'm looking for but I don't know what to do.

One example is I don't know where to put the function persist(cb) in anki or even where to call it in anki either.  I think if I had example deck and card it would answer all my questions and get me going.

I can get the first example to work, document.write("Javascript!");

I apologize for any lack of clarity.  I'm very tired and about to give up so I thought I'd come here as my last resort.  I appreciate it if someone would point me to a hand-holding guide.  Thanks.

Comment: [The addon anki-persistence](https://github.com/SimonLammer/anki-persistence) helped me to get persistence into Anki. The documentation in the Github repository contains a minimal working example. You can take a look at it to understand how that add-on should be used.

Comment: I gave up on it already.  It must be beyond my current comprehension.   I created a docker container with a website builtin.  One webpage for each study item.  Paste the url in Anki and click it when it's due.  The webpage does everything I want.  Perhaps if I'm a little smarter in the future I'll figure it out.